# No GPS data Neo 6M DFRduino Nano

Tags: serial, arduino-nano, softwareserial, gps, tinygps

I checked several answers for same question but none of them help.

I also changed the nano board and GPS module but without luck. I ran it outdoor.

[This post question](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/25901/not-getting-data-from-gps) had same issue except my date **does not display the correct date and time**.

My connection:

```
vcc->5V
rxd->d4  
txd->d3  
gnd->gnd
```

FullExample program from TinyGPS++, I get following types of entries

```
Sats HDOP  Latitude   Longitude   Fix  Date       Time     Date Alt    Course Speed Card  Distance Course Card  Chars Sentences Checksum
           (deg)      (deg)       Age                      Age  (m)    --- from GPS ----  ---- to London  ----  RX    RX        Fail
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
0    100.0  ********** *********** **** 00/00/2000 00:00:00 152  ****** ****** ***** ***   ******** ****** ***   324   0         0        
0    100.0  ********** *********** **** 00/00/2000 00:00:00 230  ****** ****** ***** ***   ******** ****** ***   486   0         0        
0    100.0  ********** *********** **** 00/00/2000 00:00:00 308  ****** ****** ***** ***   ******** ****** ***   648   0         0        
0    100.0  ********** *********** **** 00/00/2000 00:00:00 384  ****** ****** ***** ***   ******** ****** ***   810   0         0        
0    100.0  ********** *********** **** 00/00/2000 00:00:00 463  ****** ****** ***** ***   ******** ****** ***   972   0         0        
0    100.0  ********** *********** **** 00/00/2000 00:00:00 541  ****** ****** ***** ***   ******** ****** ***   1134  0         0
```

NMEA read from serial

```
$GPGGA,,,,,,0,00,99.99,,,,,,*48
$GPGSA,A,1,,,,,,,,,,,,,99.99,99.99,99.99*30
$GPGSV,1,1,01,05,,,20*7F
$GPGLL,,,,,,V,N*64
$GPRMC,,V,,,,,,,,,,N*53
$GPVTG,,,,,,,,,N*30

$GPGGA,,,,,,0,00,99.99,,,,,,*48
$GPGSA,A,1,,,,,,,,,,,,,99.99,99.99,99.99*30
$GPGSV,1,1,01,14,,,29*76
$GPGLL,,,,,,V,N*64
$GPRMC,,V,,,,,,,,,,N*53
$GPVTG,,,,,,,,,N*30
```

**UPDATE:**

I change the antenna. At some time I got this. From the GPGSV sentence I know that there are about 15 16 satellites in view but the FullExample only show 0.

```
$GPRMC,,V,,,,,,,,,,N*53
$GPVTG,,,,,,,,,N*30
$GPGGA,,,,,,0,00,99.99,,,,,,*48
$GPGSA,A,1,,,,,,,,,,,,,99.99,99.99,99.99*30
$GPGSV,4,1,15,04,,,31,07,,,33,09,,,34,11,,,30*74
$GPGSV,4,2,15,12,,,33,13,,,30,14,,,33,15,,,27*7D
$GPGSV,4,3,15,16,,,33,19,,,34,20,,,30,21,,,33*70
$GPGSV,4,4,15,22,,,32,23,,,33,33,,,35*7B
$GPGLL,,,,,,V,N*64

$GPRMC,,V,,,,,,,,,,N*53
$GPVTG,,,,,,,,,N*30
$GPGGA,,,,,,0,00,99.99,,,,,,*48
$GPGSA,A,1,,,,,,,,,,,,,99.99,99.99,99.99*30
$GPGSV,4,1,16,04,,,32,07,,,33,08,,,31,09,,,33*7A
$GPGSV,4,2,16,11,,,29,12,,,33,13,,,30,14,,,34*73
$GPGSV,4,3,16,15,,,32,16,,,33,19,,,33,20,,,31*73
$GPGSV,4,4,16,21,,,33,22,,,33,23,,,34,33,,,35*7D
$GPGLL,,,,,,V,N*64
```

My idea now is to supply external power for the DFRduino Nano

Any idea how I can continue. Should I changed to other type of gps module?

Comment: *"I ran it outdoor"* Under a clear sky and for some number of minutes, right?

Comment: @timemage yes. From this [post](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/8273/ublox-neo-6m-gps-module-not-responding), it takes 1 or 2 hours to charge EEPROM and the onboard RTC. Without RTC syc time, it cannot get correct date time in my case

Comment: You just have made some interpretation with with my name. I wasn't asking about time/RTC output at all. *Only* that you had it where we could be *certain* that you would get a fix at the end of so many minutes if everything were correct. So many avoid this. With your update it seems whatever software is involved is correct so far as it goes. Check your antenna connections, that nothing (including the Arduino) near is injecting interference, and try powering it from different sources.

Comment: @timemage With 5V power supply from Nano I got the module damaged (Rx Tx get shorten), do you have any idea?

Comment: A short has nothing to do with the problem here. Besides that shortening RX and TX doesn't damage anything (unless you connect two TX pins)

Comment: If I had to guess you're referring to getting the directions incorrect when trying to use a Nano as only a transceiver. The Nano's RX and TX are labeled from the perspective of the AVR and are 5V (most GPS are 3.3V). The 1K series resistors on the Nano's RX/TX limit the trouble you can get into here if the AVR was in reset. But I don't really understand what you're saying. You should edit any new information directly into the question.

Comment: @timemage I connected as mention above. For a while ( 5 6 hours running) the RX TX do not working any more. They got shorten. From [this forum](https://forum.arduino.cc/t/neo-6m-gps-modules-vcc/1013042/3), power supply for NEO 6M should typically be 3.0V and range: 2.7V to 3.6V while I supplied 5V

Comment: Glad you got it working. I dunno that I've heard someone use "short" in the way that you are.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ceramic antenna is the issue. I changed to the external 1.5GHz one. It got fix under 5 seconds